# Careers - add codepen.io

Tags: feature-request, jobs

add codepen.io portfolio to the Careers profile page.
I have tons of code examples and things i've created that would GREATLY influence potential clients' decision if to hire me or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can already do this. You can add an open source project from anywhere - we don't need to add support for every single website.

Just click "other" when adding a project to your profile:

[image: Add an open source project from another location]

Then enter your CodePen URL and we'll populate the form with details:

[image: Adding a project from CodePen]

Comment: I was thinking more like Carrers would scrap my top pens and automatically insert them in a easy-to-view manner. I put my own profile page there, not every pen I have, since i have way too many.  i'm talking more of proper integration aspect, since codepen is such an important, game-changing website, just like stackoverflow is.